# Wp pagination for custom database table

Tags: pagination

I am trying to create pagination for my custom database loop, but it doesnt work. I copy codes below and anybody tell me what s wrong?

```
global $wpdb;
$tablom = $wpdb->prefix . 'pasla';
$tablom2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'users';
$query = "SELECT ".$tablom.".id as id, ".$tablom.".sonuc as pasla_sonuc, ".$tablom2.".id as userID, pasla_tarih, paslanan_marka, ".$tablom.".telefon as pasla_telefon, ".$tablom.".kazanc as pasla_kazanc, ".$tablom.".ad_soyad as pasla_ad_soyad, pasla_tarih, ".$tablom2.".display_name as userPersonName FROM ".$tablom." inner join ".$tablom2." on ".$tablom2.".ID=".$tablom.".user_id where ".$tablom.".user_id=".$current_user->ID;
$total = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (${query}) AS combined_table" );
$items_per_page = 4;
$page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
$offset = ( $page * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( $query . " ORDER BY pasla_tarih LIMIT ${offset}, ${items_per_page}" );                    
foreach($myrows as $row){
    if ( $row->pasla_sonuc == 0 ){
        echo '
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12-col-lg-12 sonuc-kutu" style="background-color: #337ab7;">
            <span>'. $row->pasla_ad_soyad .' - '. (new DateTime($row->pasla_tarih))->format("d/m/Y") .' - #'. $row->id .'</span>
            <p>'. $row->paslanan_marka .' markasına '. (new DateTime($row->pasla_tarih))->format("d/m/Y") .' tarihinde talep etmiş olduğunuz #'. $row->id .' no\'lu pasla işleminiz bekleme sürecindedir. Bu paslayı satış ile sonuçlanmasını hızlandırmak için pasladığınız müşteriyi arayarak ya da görüşerek ikna edebilirsiniz. #'. $row->id .' no\'lu pasla işleminiz ile ilgili gelişmeler tekrar aktarılacaktır.</p>
            </div>
            ';
    }elseif($row->pasla_sonuc == 1  ){
        echo '
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12-col-lg-12 sonuc-kutu" style="background-color: #20b979;">
        <span>'. $row->pasla_ad_soyad .' - '. (new DateTime($row->pasla_tarih))->format("d/m/Y") .' - #'. $row->id .'</span>
        <p>TEBRİKLER! '. $row->paslanan_marka .' markasına '. (new DateTime($row->pasla_tarih))->format("d/m/Y") .' tarihinde talep etmiş olduğunuz #'. $row->id .' no\'lu pasla işleminiz satış ile sonuçlanmıştır. Kazanç tutarınız olan '. $row->pasla_kazanc .' hesabınıza kazanç tutarı olarak eklenmiştir. Kazanç tutarınızı istediğiniz zaman banka hesabına aktararak kullanabilirsiniz. Güle güle harcayın...</p>
        </div>
        ';
    }elseif($row->pasla_sonuc == 2  ){
        echo '
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12-col-lg-12 sonuc-kutu" style="background-color: #818181;">
        <span>'. $row->pasla_ad_soyad .' - '. (new DateTime($row->pasla_tarih))->format("d/m/Y") .' - #'. $row->id .'</span>
        <p>Üzgünüz! '. $row->paslanan_marka .' markasına '. (new DateTime($row->pasla_tarih))->format("d/m/Y") .' tarihinde talep etmiş olduğunuz #'. $row->id .' no\'lu pasla işleminiz malesef '. $row->pasla_ad_soyad .' tarafından red edilmiştir.Dilerseniz tekrardan pasladığınız kişi ile irtibat kurarak ikna edebilir ya da yeni paslalar için Kazandıran Markalar sayfamızı ziyaret edebilirsiniz.</p>
        </div>
        ';
    }
}  
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
    'total' => ceil($total / $items_per_page),
    'current' => $page
));
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this code to your `functions.php` file:

```
$customPagHTML     = "";
$query             = "SELECT * FROM custom_table";
$total_query     = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (${query}) AS combined_table";
$total             = $wpdb->get_var( $total_query );
$items_per_page = 4;
$page             = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
$offset         = ( $page * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;
$result         = $wpdb->get_results( $query . " ORDER BY field DESC LIMIT ${offset}, ${items_per_page}" );
$totalPage         = ceil($total / $items_per_page);

if($totalPage > 1){
$customPagHTML     =  '<div><span>Page '.$page.' of '.$totalPage.'</span>'.paginate_links( array(
'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
'format' => '',
'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
'total' => $totalPage,
'current' => $page
)).'</div>';
}
```

To display the output in your template, use:

```
echo $customPagHTML;
```

Comment: If you're going to copy/paste, at least credit the [original source](http://www.walkswithme.net/wordpress-pagination-for-custom-tables).